# C++ variant and variant subsets

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, variant-type

I seem to be in a love-hate relationship with C++. It can make some parts of your code elegant and easy to grasp, and some others become an inconceivable mess. And it's not the language itself causing the problem, but the allure of some language constructs which can lead to many headaches in the long run.

I have a collision detection engine for different object shapes. I have a category of convex particles, which share a common base class, and (at the moment only one) non-convex shapes.

Here is an example of a few shapes, where I have replaced the true functions with some easy-to-test ones:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/polymorphic_get.hpp>

class Convex{
public:
    virtual ~Convex(void){};
    virtual void print(void)const = 0;
};

class Sphere: public Convex{
public:
    void print(void)const{
        printf("This is a sphere!\n");
    }
};

class Cone: public Convex{
public:
    void print(void)const{
        printf("This is a cone!\n");
    }
};
```

Now, since I need to perform different operations based on the type, and because performance is critical, I thought `boost::variant` would be great for this case, so I defined:

```
class Complex;
typedef boost::variant<Sphere, Cone, Complex> ShapeVariant;
```

where `class Complex` is defined as:

```
void print_shape(const ShapeVariant& shape);
class Complex{
public:
    Complex(const std::vector<ShapeVariant>& shapes):
        shapes_(shapes)
    {}
    void print_shapes(void)const{
        printf("This is a complex!\n");
        for(const auto& shape: shapes_) print_shape(shape);
    }
    const std::vector<ShapeVariant>& get_shapes(void)const{
        return shapes_;
    }
private:
    std::vector<ShapeVariant> shapes_;
};
```

and `print_shape`'s definition is:

```
class PrintShapeVisitor: public boost::static_visitor<void> {
public:
    void operator()(const Complex& comp){
        comp.print_shapes();
    }
    template<typename T>
    void operator()(const T& rest){
        rest.print();
    }
};
void print_shape(const ShapeVarian& shape){
    boost::apply_visitor(PrintShapeVisitor(), shape);
}
```

Now, this works well, but I get into trouble when I want to introduce a `Hull` class, which takes an ensemble of `Convex` objects, since I need to store these as `ShapeVariant` (In the original code, I need to be able to serialize these shapes):

```
class Hull;
typedef boost::variant<Sphere, Cone, Hull> ConvexShapeVariant;

class Hull: public Convex{
public:
    Hull(const std::vector<ConvexShapeVariant>& shapes):
        shapes_(shapes)
    {}
    void print(void)const{
        printf("This is a hull!\n");
        for(const auto& shape: shapes_) boost::polymorphic_get<Convex>(shape).print();
    }
    const std::vector<ConvexShapeVariant>& get_shapes(void)const{
        return shapes_;
    }
private:
    std::vector<ConvexShapeVariant> shapes_;
};
```

and `ShapeVariant` needs to be updated to:

```
typedef boost::variant<Sphere, Cone, Hull, Complex> ShapeVariant;
```

Now things start to get problematic, and sometimes I even need to `reinterpret_cast` a `ConvexShapeVariant` to a `ShapeVariant`.

One alternative would be to have an enum:

```
enum eShapetype{
    SPHERE,
    CONE,
    HULL,
    CONVEX,
    COMPLEX
};
```

and make all shapes derive from a common `class Shape` base class:

```
class Shape{
public:
   ~Shape(void){};
   virtual eShapeType type(void)const = 0;
};
```

where now `Shape` would replace `ShapeVariant` in functionality:

```
void print_shape(const Shape& shape){
    if(shape.type() < CONVEX) static_cast<const Convex&>(shape).print(); 
    else static_cast<const Complex&>(shape).print_shapes();
}
```

[Here](https://ideone.com/ffXXmg) is a working example of this case.

In essence, what I present here are different methods to perform 'pattern matching' on the data type, a concept that is a feature of other programming languages.

So, what do you think are the pros and cons of each of these methods. Do you have any alternative recommendations? Which one would you choose if you wanted high performance (the `Convex` methods are going to be called very often), and preferably clean code.

Comment: There is never a best way. Is there anything specific you have in mind?

Comment: Or, rather, there is never a best *general* way. There is a best way given certain constraints.

Comment: You both are right! I edited my question.

Comment: You have a little typo - `void print_shape(const ShapeVarian& shape);` should probably be `void print_shape(const ShapeVariant& shape);` (missing the `t`).

Comment: Have you looked at [this paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3449.pdf)? It seems like what you need. May be you could implement things in the paper. Here is the [link](https://parasol.tamu.edu/~yuriys/pm/) for the library itself. **EDIT**:  [right link](https://github.com/solodon4/Mach7)

Comment: I prefer the second version (without variants) -- you're already using virtual inheritance from a common base, so a using a variant on top of this is redundant because it just duplicates what you get from virtual classes alone.  I think the aggregate classes (`Hull` and `Complex`) should own their pointers and be responsible for their destruction, though.  And I don't see why `Complex` doesn't have `print`, like `Hull`, so you could avoid its ugly special case in the `print_shape` function.

Comment: @ChristopherOicles Note that not all shapes in the variant implementation inherit from a common base, only `Sphere`, `Cone`, and `Hull`. `Complex` is not `Convex` itself. As this is an example, I didn't bother with ownership (there are also reasons to not own their pointers). Also, `Complex` has `print_shape` instead of `print` so as to make the distinction with `Convex` more apparent. `Complex` doesn't have to share any functionality with other shape types.

Comment: @OlzhasZhumabek Thanks, it's a long paper, but I will check it out. But from quickly going through, it just provides means to do pattern matching on e.g. an existing inheritance hierarchy, which would apply with my second implementation. I'm also curious to see how it's performance fairs with boost::variant.

Comment: In the future, please refrain from using `<pre><code>` and use indentation instead.  You could then use `<>` instead of `&lt` and `&gt`.